# Selenium findElements not working with 'contains' to fetch elements with partial id matches

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to fetch all the elements from a web page which matches partial ID.

My Elements have xPath as:

```
//[@id="job_1462770933035_0020.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a
```

I am trying to filter all such elements using the following code but nothing is returned:

```
List<WebElement> AllElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,\"FileSystemCounter\")]"));
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: //*[contains(@id, 'FileSystemCounter')]/tbody/tr[1]/td/a  to collect all td in first tr

Comment: Hi Murali, that didnt work, I have multiple elements like:
//*[@id="job_1462770933035_0020.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]

//*[@id="job_1462770933035_0020.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]

//*[@id="job_1462770933035_0020.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]
How can i fetch all such elements in a list?

Comment: you can, can u plz paste HTML code of those

Comment: Hi Murali, HTML code for my elements are listed in my comment above. Please let me know if anything else is needed...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

```
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//give the first tr xpath here"));
List<WebElement> tdList=ele.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
```

Comment: Hi, Tried using the following:
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath(FileSystemCounters+"/​tbody/tr[1]"));
  List<WebElement> AllElements=ele.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
But it failed at first line stating: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Error Message => 'Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id="job_1462770933035_0020.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter"]/​tbody/tr[1] because of the following error:
Error: INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 51'

Comment: It may be because you are providing the wrong xpath and hence it is unable to locate the element in the webpage. If you are using firefox, then use firepath to inspect the "tr" element and extract the xpath from there.

Comment: If possible can you provide the xpath of the webtable from where you are extracting the values ?